# Lift framework with java

Tags: java, scala, jakarta-ee, lift

I'm building a web application that needs high performance. I intended using Java EE but after researching about it, there are many negative comments about Java EE applications.

I'm thinking about the Lift framework, but it seems that Lift only support Scala, and I only know Java. Does Lift actually support Java? (I can't find any project example that uses Lift with java). I downloaded a Lift framework project application and there is a boot file in it, can we create a same boot file but for Java?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Lift is Scala only.  If you're looking for high performance and Java then you should check out the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) as it also has the benefit of not requiring a Servlet container to be deployed.

Comment: I don't know Zoo Keeper that well but I always thought it to be back end agnostic

Answer (score 2):

The Lift framework is Scala only. I want to note that in my experience the transition from Java to Scala was not that hard and now that I know it, there are many language features that make development easier and faster for me. You can take a look at this guide for transitioning between languages: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/960 to see if it might be something that might be right for you. From experience, I really enjoy using the Lift framework as it offers a lot of performance and functionality. The documentation is a bit lacking, but the community is great and makes up for that if you get stuck.

As for Java EE having negative comments, that is a bit vague. The Java EE spec includes everything from Servlets to JSF and EJB. Parts of the spec you will find in almost any web framework (including Lift) and others are more specialized. JSF for example has a lot of overhead, but tries to simplify a lot of the typical application lifecycle. EJB similarly tries to simplify the persistence layer through object relationship management (ORM).

High performance sites can be accomplished with most frameworks, but a lot of it will come down how you develop it. Also, because the framework supports it does not mean you need to use  a particular component. Spring (http://www.springsource.org/) is a framework that many people have used on high performance sites, and is incredibly configurable (Supports EJB and JSF, but you don't need to use it). Also, Wicket (http://wicket.apache.org/) is a Java framework that offers a similar feel to Lift that might be interesting to you.

Comment: > EJB similarly tries to simplify the persistence layer through object relationship management (ORM). - That's not entirely correct. There is no ORM functionality in the current version of EJB. EJB simplifies working with JPA, which is an ORM, but it by itself is ORM agnostic and does not contain any ORM code (anymore).

Comment: >JSF for example has a lot of overhead - Where exactly is this overhead in then? And compared to what? Last time I looked JSF had slightly better performance and a lower session footprint than for instance Wicket.

Comment: My point was that generally most abstraction layers like that add overhead, but that is not all there is to the J2EE spec. With regards to EJB, you are correct EJB does no longer provide ORM. With regards to JSF, it has been my experience that the 6 lifecycle phases have added a performance overhead to our applications - that while can be worked around, typically requires more resources than alternative frameworks. As for Wicket, I mentioned that really as a framework that is similar to Lift.

Comment: Actually, Wicket is rather similar to JSF in many aspects. The 6 lifecycle phases do things that every other web app or framework does anyway, namely getting a template from somewhere, getting values from the request, converting and validating those values, calling some business logic and then rendering results. If there are no values posted, it's just getting a template and rendering it. Do alternative web frameworks not do this as well?

Comment: Sure, other frameworks have methods for performing that functionality albeit often not so simply. JSF aimed to provide a simple, standard way to handle the process. For example, validation is as easy as passing a validator to an input tag but that has overhead and there is an expense to that overhead. You are right that others provide that functionality but they do not necessarily have to go through  deserializing an object phase, validating phase, then to error handling, and so on. The more control you have, the more complex the setup, but the greater control you have over performance.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Lift only for a year now, and was never really interested if it would run from java (I wanted to learn new effective conceptions anyway).
So, I don't fully know the subject. But what I know for sure is that Liftweb has java methods almost everywhere to support java, too. So, you can build your app if not fully in java, then most part of it.
Prooflinks are like these:
http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/net/liftweb/actor/LiftActorJ.html
Classes that add support for java by adding java-acceptable method names and such. These classes usually have a "J" letter at the end.

Anyway, I'd suggest to try out Scala, too -- it's great. And even if you use java only -- you probably will get used to Scala anyway, because you probably would want to read the source code sometimes.